# Why does this Query return NULL?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, prepared-statement, derby

I have a derby users database which I query, when the user clicks login on the application.

However, when I query the users table with the parameter [user] derby returns a null Object instead of the record it ought to return.

Here is my code:

```
String ssql = "SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE UNAME LIKE ?";
   try{
       DriverManager.registerDriver(new org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver());
       con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
       sql = con.prepareStatement(ssql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
       sql.setString(1, cbox_chooseUser.getSelectedItem().toString());
       sql.executeQuery();
       ResultSet rs = sql.getGeneratedKeys();
           try{
              while (rs.next()) {
                 if(rs.getString("PW").toCharArray().equals(txt_password.getPassword())){
                     sql.close();
                     con.close();
                     return true;
                  }
             } catch (NPE ...) {...}
    }
```

I tried it multiple times wit a test user with both the pw and the username set to "test"; but I always get the same error.
Why is the recordset always Null?

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: executeQuery already returns the resultset. And: You should not use "Select *". You want "PW" so "Select PW" ...

Comment: Which keys would be generated from a SELECT statement ? Did you mean `ResultSet rs = sql.executeQuery();` ?

Comment: How about you post the string result from `ResultSet`?

Comment: Outside that: You are not saving passwords in clear text, do you? http://stackoverflow.com/a/1054033/982149

Comment: *FYI:* `toCharArray()` returns a `char[]` and `equals()` doesn't work on arrays. The `if` statement will always be false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getGeneratedKeys()) says

> **ResultSet *getGeneratedKeys()* throws SQLException**
>
> Retrieves any auto-generated keys created as a result of executing this Statement
>   object.
>
> *If this Statement object did not generate any keys, **an empty
>   ResultSet object** is returned.*

Your select statement isn't generating any keys that's why it's returning an empty ResultSet. You aren't inserting anything hence no keys are being generated.

You can try `ResultSet rs = sql.executeQuery();`. It should work.

Answer (score 1):

You are using it in wrong way.

The generated keys concept should be used only in the case DML of `insert` type query but not in the case of `select` query.

`select` simply select the rows from the table. In this case there is no chance of any keys getting generated.

In the case of `insert` query if any column is configured as `auto increment` or kind of functionality then some keys will get generated. These keys can be caught using `Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS` in java.

As you are using `select` query there is no need of using `Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS`.

You just modify below lines and everything will be fine.

```
sql = con.prepareStatement(ssql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
sql.setString(1, cbox_chooseUser.getSelectedItem().toString());
sql.executeQuery();
ResultSet rs = sql.getGeneratedKeys();
```

with

```
sql = con.prepareStatement( ssql );
sql.setString( 1, cbox_chooseUser.getSelectedItem().toString() );
ResultSet rs = sql.executeQuery();
```